# How to remove the border of a Scipy generated and Matplotlib plotted dendrogram without remove the labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy, dendrogram

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy as hier


df = pd.read_excel('some_symmetricmatrix.xlsx')

Z = hier.linkage(df, 'ward')            
hier.set_link_color_palette(['#d95f02','#7570b3'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xlabel('Distance')

den = hier.dendrogram(
    Z,
    leaf_font_size=10., 
    orientation = 'left',
    above_threshold_color= '#1b9e77'
)

ax.tick_params(axis='x',top='off')


plt.savefig('somedendrogram.png', bbox_inches='tight', transparent = True, dpi = 300)
plt.close()
```

This give me an image like this:
[image]

I would like to remove the borders (or axes) of the dendrogram, but I would like to keep the ticks and the labels. I've already tried 2 methods from the net: 
1. add `ax.axis('off')` to the code
2. use [this piece of code](https://codeyarns.com/2015/06/29/how-to-hide-axis-of-plot-in-matplotlib/) to turn the visibility of the axes off.
Both of these give this:
[image]

I tried to Google this, but I couldn't find anything. I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution there.